# Instabug Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Dialog.dismiss()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, instabug

Getting crashes inside Instabug on Android app.  This is from the store version of the app so I do not have steps to reproduce.  Thank you!

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Dialog.dismiss()' on a null object reference
at com.instabug.library.m.c(InstabugDelegate.java:455)
at com.instabug.library.activity.a.onClick(InstabugInvocationDialog.java:99)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21179)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: Please add part of your code when you handle dialog ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You are trying to `dismiss()` a `Dialog` that is `null`. That causes a `NullPointerException`. This happens in the `InstabugDelegate.java` source file on row 455. I don't think there's anything more than can be told with the information given and that was already said on the first two lines of the crash log. Maybe just report the problem to Instabug developers...

Answer (score 0):

This bug should be solved in later versions.

Can you try out v2.3.1 and tell me how it goes?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved since version 3.0.5.
You just need to upgrade to latest version >= v3.0.5